# How to properly allocate memory to double pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I have this function:

```c
void marray_read( size_t* size, size_t* array[] ) {
    *size = read_size();
    *array = malloc(sizeof(size_t) * *size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        size_t s = read_size();
        *array[i] = s;
    }
}
```

I need to allocate memory for `array` array and fill it.

And when I assign `*array[i] = s` on the second iteration of the cycle there is `Segmentation Fault`. (I know that `s` is correct).

How to properly allocate memory to `array` in the 3rd line and assign variable in 6th line?

Comment: [Edit] and show the code that calls `marray_read` including the relevant declarations.

Comment: Is this for a 2D array or a pointer-based look-up table? The ways to allocate are different. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: I think it should be `(*array)[i] = s;`.

Comment: Yes, this is part of code for 2D array. `array` is present as length of each row here.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, `marray_read` could work only if it is passed an array that already exists (by passing the address of the first element of such an array in the `array` parameter). This is because the use of `array[i]` requires that `array` be a pointer to the first of several elements.

You may have intended to the `array` parameter to point to a pointer that will be filled in with the address of memory allocated for an array of `size_t` objects. In this case, the array declaration should be:

```
void marray_read(size_t *size, size_t **array)
```

and this line:

```
*array[i] = s;
```

should be:

```
(*array)[i] = s;
```

While the parameter declarations `size_t *array[]` and `size_t **array` are effectively the same for the compiler, the former incorrectly expresses to the reader that `array` is intended to point to (the first element of) an array of `size_t *` objects. The latter is what is usually used for a pointer to a pointer to the first element of an array of `size_t` objects.

The prior code `*array[i]` is wrong because `array[i]` is processed before `*`, so it attempts to access elements of an array where there is none. `(*array)` must be used so that the pointer at `array` is read first, and then `(*array)[i]` calculates the address of an element in an array that starts at `(*array)`.